# Copy image file from server to disk in PHP

Tags: php, save

I have a js script that saves an image as .jpg in a specific folder on the server:

```
$data = substr($_POST['imageData'], strpos($_POST['imageData'], ",") + 1);
$decodedData = base64_decode($data);
$fp = fopen("imgdownload/cc.jpg", 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
fclose($fp);
```

The next step would be for the user to save it on his/her disk, the best would be to open a dialog box "save as" and choose the name and location, but just forcing download to a set location would be a dream.

I've tried:

```
$file = 'imgdownload/cc.jpg';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

And other things without success. What am I doing wrong and how to do it right?

EDIT - this is my JS:

```
savePicture: function() {
    $(this.el).find('canvas').attr('id', 'myCanvas');
    var data = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL();
    $.post("api/process.php", {
        imageData: data
    }, function(data) {
        //window.location = data;
    });
},
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you download? on the first look one thing that could be better is just your content type. Also you are using a relative path that could be a problem.. so let's say when they download the file exists... what ecactly happens in your browser?

Comment: I dont think you can force a 'save as' dialog, since this is a browser setting... People can choose to automatically download it to a preferred folder...

Comment: What happens: the image gets to the server (with the first part of the code), and in Chrome in the Response section of Network (Web Developer Tools) I get a response like: "
1 requests ❘ 513 KB transferred
HeadersPreviewResponseCookiesTiming
�PNG


IHDR����{� IDATx^��y�n�Q'V�r�����o#BH��Fh�X0��6�$�{��x�����p�#<��c&I�ʃX4��p�1��a&4��[j��B-��zQ/���[����:y�T�w�y߻o�G�}���s�Teee�........"

If it comes to the content type, I've changed it to image/jpg, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Well, so you're getting the image data back. Great, exactly what you want. Random guess: are you submitting the image via AJAX?

Comment: I use $.post - I edited the question and added the js code. So how to move forward now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot trigger a download in response to a background AJAX request. You'll have to direct the main browser to the URL where the download occurs. E.g., in your AJAX callback:

```
window.location = '/download.php';
```

That means you'll need to store the file server-side in the AJAX upload request to then have it available for download in the separate following request to `download.php` somewhere.